# keyboard.send no envía un carácter numérico

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, keyboard, autohotkey

Para aprender Python me propuse una especie de autohotkey, pero ya casi al final del proyecto, cuando uso`keyboard.send`** para enviar pulsaciones de teclas desde una lista se pierde siempre el carácter `5`.

Intente todo lo que se me ocurrió, pensaba que el `5` no estaba siendo agregada a la lista por lo que realice un `print` antes del `keyboard.send` y si esta el `5` pero no lo envía el `keyboard.send`.

```
import keyboard
import random

pota=[1,2,3,4,5,"q","w","e","r"]
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "esc":
    print("You pressed esc")
    break

    if keyboard.is_pressed("7"):
    print("You pressed 7")
    random.shuffle(pota,random.random)
    print(pota)                            #muestra el contenido de pota después del random

    for lista in pota:                       #recorre pota
        print(lista)                        #imprime cada carácter de pota
        keyboard.send(lista)                 #envía pota como teclado.
```

Si cambio el `5` por un `6` en la lista, si aparece el `5` en los campos de texto pero desaparece el `4`.

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("7"):
```

otra duda en el código activo el script con el 7 y me envía el `random` por teclado. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el 7 no sea enviado por teclado?

Ej `pulsacion 7: 71w3r42eq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás enviando lo que crees que estás enviando, no envías la tecla con el <kbd>1</kbd>, el <kbd>2</kbd>, el <kbd>3</kbd> el <kbd>4</kbd> y el <kbd>5</kbd>.

Como los **números en tu lista son enteros y no cadenas**, son tratados como [scan codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode) (códigos numéricos que envía el teclado y que representan las teclas por su posición), en mi caso:

> ```
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("esc")
> (1,)
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("1")
> (2, 79)
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("2")
> (3, 80)
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("3")
> (4, 81)
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("4")
> (5, 75)
> >>> keyboard.key_to_scan_codes("5")
> (6, 76)
> ```

Es decir lo que envías realmente es:

> ```
> >>> keyboard.send(1)
> # No muestra nada, es la tecla ESC.
> >>> keyboard.send(2)
> 1
> >>> keyboard.send(3)
> 2
> >>> keyboard.send(4)
> 3
> >>> keyboard.send(5)
> 4
> >>> keyboard.send(6)
> 5
> ```

O haces que todos los items sean cadenas:

```
pota = ["1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5", "q", "w", "e", "r"]
```

o conviertes explícitamente a cadena al llamar a `keyboard.send`:

```
keyboard.send(str(lista))
```

o usas los scan codes correctos para cada número, poco práctico y portable, pero bueno:

```
pota = [2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, "q", "w", "e", "r"]
# o también
pota = [79, 80, 81, 75, 76, "q", "w", "e", "r"]
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! ahora entiendo y solucione el problema!! :)